# Equiv. to Coalesce() in XAML Binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, coalesce, targetnullvalue

In SQL I can do this:

```
Select Coalesce(Property1, Property2, Property3, 'All Null') as Value
From MyTable
```

If Property1, 2 and 3 are all null, then I get 'All Null'

How do I do this in XAML? I tried the following, but no luck:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Item x:Key="MyData" 
                Property1="{x:Null}"
                Property2="{x:Null}"
                Property3="Hello World" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock DataContext="{StaticResource MyData}">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <PriorityBinding TargetNullValue="All Null">
            <Binding Path="Property1" />
            <Binding Path="Property2" />
            <Binding Path="Property3" />
        </PriorityBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

The result should be 'Hello World' but instead it is 'All Null'

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd have to build a custom [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) to do that and use a MultiBinding. [PriorityBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx) uses the  first binding in the collection that produces a value successfully. In your case, the Property1 binding resolves immediately, so it's used. Since Property1 is null, the TargetNullValue is used.

A converter like this:

```
public class CoalesceConverter : System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
            object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null)
            return null;
        foreach (var item in values)
            if (item != null)
                return item;
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, 
            object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And MultiBinding like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Item x:Key="MyData" 
                Property1="{x:Null}"
                Property2="{x:Null}"
                Property3="Hello World" />
    <local:CoalesceConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock DataContext="{StaticResource MyData}">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Property1" />
            <Binding Path="Property2" />
            <Binding Path="Property3" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it all in XAML

Comment: @Jerry - Yeah, once you have the converter setup you can :-)

Comment: A 4th Property on the class could do it, too; I suppose.

Comment: @Jerry - Yeah, that would work also `return this.Property1 ?? this.Property2 ?? this.Property3;`

Comment: actually it would not because of INotifyPropertyChanged events not firing. I realize you could fake the event. But the converter handles it all.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are binding to a `String`, null is a valid value for the `PriorityBinding`. I'm not sure what your Item class's property types are, but if you use `Object`, and set them to `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`, you will get the behavior you are looking for.

The [PriorityBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx) documentation's remarks section describes how it works in more detail.

Comment: The only unfortunate part of this solution is the reliance on the Presentation assemblies inside my Entity Library. You are right, they are strings in this sample. I think making them Object would too loosely type my objects (esp. for just the sake of the XAML) ;) Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yeah, in that case I'd definitely go with @CodeNaked's solution.

Comment: I don't want to use `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` in the model classes in order to not to depend on GUI specifics there.

Answer (score 0):

The `PriorityBinding` is only looking for `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` to advance to the next `Binding`. Since `Property1` exists it is set and the `PriorityBinding` is taking the value of it.

For a pure XAML solution, this `Style` will do the job:

```
   <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Text"
                        Value="{Binding Property1}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Property1}"
                                 Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Text"
                                Value="{Binding Property2}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Property1}"
                                       Value="{x:Null}" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Property2}"
                                       Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Text"
                                Value="{Binding Property3}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Property1}"
                                       Value="{x:Null}" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Property2}"
                                       Value="{x:Null}" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Property3}"
                                       Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Text"
                                Value="All Null" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

Although, it's a bit convoluted way of doing it, and IMHO, doesn't belong in the UI but in the ViewModel.

Comment: Oh well, need to type faster... :)