# Binding to second property if first is null in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, data-binding

I have a class in which the name of the object can be null.

```
public class Thing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The identifier of the thing
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This will never be null.
    /// </remarks>
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the thing
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This MAY be null. When it isn't, it is more descriptive than Identifier.
    /// </remarks>
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In a Silverlight ListBox, I use a DataTemplate where I have the name bound to a TextBlock:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ThingTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, this obviously doesn't look very good if the Name is null. Ideally, I would want to use something equivalent to

```
string textBlockContent = thing.Name != null ? thing.Name : thing.Identifier;
```

but I can't change my model object. Is there any good way to do this?

I thought about using a Converter, but it seems to me I'd have to bind the converter to the object itself, and not the Name property. This would be fine, but how would I then rebind when either Name or Identifier changes? `IValueConverter` doesn't appear to have any way to force a reconvert if I would manually listen on my object's `INotifyPropertyChanged` event.

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equiv. to Coalesce() in XAML Binding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947728/equiv-to-coalesce-in-xaml-binding)

Comment: Be specific. Is it silverlight, or WPF?

Comment: You can't do this without changing code, as far as I know. If you found a way using strictly XAML, it would most likely be considered a hack.

Comment: @Nawaz: Silverlight. I added 'Silverlight' to the title to make it more explicit.

Comment: Can you create a wrapper object for your model? That way it could listen for property changes for both `Name` and `Identifier` and output the correct property in either case.

Comment: @Gabe: I've created wrappers for other parts of my application, and that may be the way to go. My ViewModel has ObservableCollection<Db.Thing>, and I may have to change that to ObservableCollection<ThingWrapper>. It's a bit more of a pain, because then when I get the data, I have to wrap it all, but it's viable. If MultiBinding were built in, that would be the way I would go, but since it isn't, wrapping might be my best option.

Comment: @Bryan: In Silverlight 5 you will be able to create a binding extension like MultiBinding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF, you can do this easily by implementing an [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx).  Unfortunately, Silverlight doesn't support this directly, though there are [workarounds written for Silverlight.](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/06/silverlight-multibindings-how-to-attached-mutiple-bindings-to-a-single-property/)

Answer (score 3):

You can change the Binding, so that it binds directly to your `Thing` instance:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ThingTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding .,Converter={StaticResource ConvertMyThingy}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then use a converter that returns either `Instance` or `Name` from the passed `Thing` instance

```
public class ConvertMyThingyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var thing= value as Thing;
        if(thing == null)
           return String.Empty;
        return thing.Name ?? thing.Identifier;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good, simple way to handle this, though it's not reusable to other types, as it requires a custom converter per type (or interface, at least).

Comment: @xor: In my model. I have two TextBoxes elsewhere in my application bound to Identifier and Name. When one of these changes, the value in the listbox needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

The `Converter` is not bind to `Name` or `Object`, it binds to `Text` property binding.
So, it will be invoked every time you assign a value to `Text`. Up to you after inside a `Converter` to choice what `Text` property will look like.

One of possible solutions is to make `NameAndIdentifier` string special property which is assignable from Converter based on Model's `Name` and `Identifier` properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom display property in your ViewModel/Presenter (or whatever you want to call it). Basically, the code you posted above must be modified, and this added to it:

```
public readonly string DisplayName
{
    get
    {
        return Name ?? Identifier;
    }
}
```

Any other way, as far as I know, is going to be a hack.

Comment: You should use the `??` operator: `return Name ?? Identifier;`. This is the best solution in general, though it's moot since the OP has said that he can't change the model.

Comment: It's worth mentioning if someone else sees this question that *can* edit their model. And good point about the `??` operator, I always forget about it. ;)